# Need help with solving the expression $(x + y)^2 = (x + 1)(y - 1)$ for $x$ and $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for $x$ and $y$ in
$(x+y)^2=(x+1)(y-1)$. I've figured out that
$$x^2+2xy+y^2=xy-x+y-1$$ but I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm somewhat familiar with solving quadratic equations by completing the square, could that help somehow? I'd appreciate any tips. 
Thanks -Kurns

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: $x, y$ are real numbers?

Comment: One solution in which both sides are zero is $x=-1,y=1$. This makes every factor in your initial factorization equal to zero.

Comment: Thanks guys, and yes, x and y are real numbers.

Comment: @Zabin Mukarjee,could you describe the steps that led to the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is $x=-1,y=1$.

If $x+1,y-1$ are both positive, then AM-GM implies their product is at most the square of their AM which is $\frac{1}{4}(x+y)^2<(x+y)^2$. If they are both negative, then $-x-1,-y+1$ are both positive and so $(x+1)(y-1)=(-x-1)(-y+1)<(-x-y)^2=(x+y)^2$. If one of $x+1,y-1$ is positive and the other negative, then their product is negative. In none of these cases can we have equality.

If one of $x+1,y-1$ is zero, then $x+y$ must be zero and hence both $x+1,y-1$ must be zero.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me, although it was a little hard to understand as a non-native English speaker.